# seaborn error for showing barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to draw a bar chart from a dataframe. Here is the dataframe
[image]
And when I try to write the codes to show the barplot it returns this error.
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`
I googled it and a lot of people added this keyword `kind="count"` but dint work at all. Here is the codes that I am using.

```
#Using seaborn to get the hours against the user_count

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

ax = sns.barplot(x= 'hours', y= 'user_count', data=dff)
ax.set(ylabel = 'User Count')
ax.set(xlabel = 'Hour of the Day')
ax.set_title('2017-06-02/ Friday')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert column `user_count` to `int`, because `dtype` is `object` what are obviously `string` values:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'hours':[0,1,2], 'user_count':['2','4','5']})
print (dff)
   hours user_count
0      0          2
1      1          4
2      2          5

print (dff.dtypes)
hours          int64
user_count    object
dtype: object

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

dff['user_count'] = dff['user_count'].astype(int)

ax = sns.barplot(x= 'hours', y= 'user_count', data=dff)
ax.set(ylabel = 'User Count')
ax.set(xlabel = 'Hour of the Day')
ax.set_title('2017-06-02/ Friday')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you!! I thought headings dint matter.

Comment: @Aurora headings don't matter, but datatypes do matter